# How can I make the two rightmost columns equal width in a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am using the Overleaf editor. I made the table below, but I want the two rightmost columns to be of equal width and centered.

When I use p{1cm} instead of |c, the texts are not centered.

Here's my code, I'm open to your suggestions:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline & & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ Predictions (by the test) } \\
\hline & & + & - \\
\hline \multirow{2}{*}{Actual (covid status)} & \centering + & 33 & 1 \\
\cline { 2 - 4 } & - & 3 & 72 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: This is a common problem, where your `\multicolumn` stretches the final two columns (columns 3 & 4). However, with the actual width being specified as `c`, their natural widths are used. This easily forces column 3 to be narrow, leaving the remaining width to be "naturally" filled by column 4... causing the final column to be wider-than-expected.

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\SetTblrInner{hspan=even}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec={Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
hlines,vlines,
cell{1}{3}={c=2}{},
cell{3}{1}={r=2}{},
}
                       &   & Predictions (by the test) &    \\
                       &   & +                         & -  \\
Actual (covid status)  & + & 33                        & 1  \\
                       & - & 3                         & 72 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @omersk The key is `hspan=even`.